# Get version attribute from a XmlDocument

Tags: xml, attributes, version, xmldocument

I have this xml in a XmlDocument:

```
<eventoMDFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/mdfe" versao="1.00">
  <infEvento Id="ID1101123317030328245800017958028000040030191042909301">
    <cOrgao>33</cOrgao>
    <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
    <CNPJ>03282458000179</CNPJ>
    <chMDFe>33170303282458000179580280000400301910429093</chMDFe>
    <dhEvento>2017-03-03T13:27:52</dhEvento>
    <tpEvento>110112</tpEvento>
    <nSeqEvento>1</nSeqEvento>
    <detEvento versaoEvento="1.00">
      <evEncMDFe>
        <descEvento>Encerramento</descEvento>
        <nProt>933170000001722</nProt>
        <dtEnc>2017-03-03</dtEnc>
        <cUF>33</cUF>
        <cMun>3305802</cMun>
      </evEncMDFe>
    </detEvento>
  </infEvento>
</eventoMDFe>
```

And i need to get the attribute value versao from eventoMDFe. In that case, i need the value "1.00".

How can i get that attribute value ?
I already tried something like:

```
    XmlNodeList elementList = pXml.GetElementsByTagName("infEvento");
    for (int i = 0; i < elementList.Count; i++)
    {
        versaoMDFe = elementList[i].Attributes["versao"].Value;
    }
```

and not worked...

Comment: I get the expected result using "eventoMDFe" instead of "infEvento" in the method before. But i dont like the solution using a loop. Maybe a better solution ?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: Hello! I'm using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can get the value without looping. It depends on the structure of your document. For example, if you only have a single `<eventoMDFe>` element then you can do any of the following.

```
string xml = @"<eventoMDFe xmlns='http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/mdfe' versao='1.00'>
  <infEvento Id='ID1101123317030328245800017958028000040030191042909301'>
    <cOrgao>33</cOrgao>
    <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
    <CNPJ>03282458000179</CNPJ>
    <chMDFe>33170303282458000179580280000400301910429093</chMDFe>
    <dhEvento>2017-03-03T13:27:52</dhEvento>
    <tpEvento>110112</tpEvento>
    <nSeqEvento>1</nSeqEvento>
    <detEvento versaoEvento='1.00'>
      <evEncMDFe>
        <descEvento>Encerramento</descEvento>
        <nProt>933170000001722</nProt>
        <dtEnc>2017-03-03</dtEnc>
        <cUF>33</cUF>
        <cMun>3305802</cMun>
      </evEncMDFe>
    </detEvento>
  </infEvento>
</eventoMDFe>";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

// Using XPath
var versaoMDFe = doc.SelectSingleNode("//@versao").Value;

// Using a slight modification to what you are currently doing
var versaoMDFe = doc.GetElementsByTagName("eventoMDFe")[0].Attributes["versao"].Value

// Yet another way
var versaoMDFe = doc.LastChild.Attributes["versao"].Value;
```

Comment: I've used the second solution using a slight modification to what i'm doing. Thanks!